# 502 Bad Gateway issue while starting Jfrog

Tags: linux, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Am trying to bring Jfrog up, in local tomcat is running and artifactory service also looking fine. But in UI jfrog is not coming up.

Getting 502 Bad Gateway error. I have shared the console log details below.

Below is the console log

```
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] operation attempt #94 failed. retrying in 1s. current error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] running retry attempt #95
[INFO ] Cluster join: Retry 95: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] operation attempt #95 failed. retrying in 1s. current error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
2022-09-10T06:14:20.271Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory, attempt number 90
2022-09-10T06:14:20.274Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - pinging artifactory attempt number 90 failed with code : ECONNREFUSED
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] running retry attempt #96
[DEBUG] Cluster join: Retry 96: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] operation attempt #96 failed. retrying in 1s. current error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
2022-09-10T06:14:21.188Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [2b4bfed554e45cf6] [join_executor.go:169          ] [main                ] [] - Cluster join: Retry 100: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: could not parse error from service registry, status code: 404, raw body: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1></body></html>
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] running retry attempt #97
[DEBUG] Cluster join: Retry 97: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] operation attempt #97 failed. retrying in 1s. current error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
2022-09-10T06:14:22.016Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [accessclient.go:60            ] [main                ] - Cluster join: Retry 100: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused [access_client]
[TRACE] [Service registry ping] running retry attempt #98
[DEBUG] Cluster join: Retry 98: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
```

and this is the error am getting in UI.

[502 Bad Gateway error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ieQs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a newly installed Artifactory instance? If yes, we need to verify whether [the required ports](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements#SystemRequirements-RequirementsMatrix:%7E:text=8081%20for%20Artifactory,for%20gRPC%20port) are in place (open at the firewall level). If the ports are already available, disable the IPv6 address from the VM where Artifactory is installed and restart the Artifactory. There are chances of this error occurrence if the application is trying to pick up the IPv6 address for initialisation instead of Ipv4.